# What is the relation between $P(X_n=x_n|X_0=x_0)$ and $P(X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1,\dots, X_n=x_n)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

For a simple random walk $X_n$ on the integer number, what is the relation between
$$P(X_n=x_n|X_0=x_0)$$
and
$$P(X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1,\dots, X_n=x_n)$$

Clearly,
$$P(X_n=x_n|X_0=x_0)=(P(X_0=x_0))^{-1}P(X_n=x_n, X_0=x_0)$$
and
$$P(X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1,\dots, X_n=x_n)=P(X_0=x_0)P(X_1=x_1|X_0=x_0)P(X_2=x_2|X_1=x_1)\cdots P(X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}|X_n=x_n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "What is the relation between....?". Your two quantities are different: in particular, the first one is a function of just two variables $x_0, x_n$, while the second one is a function of $n+1$ variables $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$.

One thing you can do is to take a union/sum over all possible values of $x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}$. The event $\{X_0=x_0, X_n=x_n\}$ can be written as a union
$$
\{X_0=x_0, X_n=x_n\}=\bigcup_{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}}\{X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1, \dots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, X_n=x_n\}.
$$
So then you get (by countable additivity of the probability function, since all the events on the right-hand side are disjoint):
\begin{align*}
P(X_0=x_0, X_n=x_n)
&=P\left(
\bigcup_{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}}\{X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1, \dots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, X_n=x_n\}
\right)\\
&=\sum_{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}}P(X_0=x_0, X_1=x_1, \dots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, X_n=x_n).
\end{align*}
(and you can divide both sides through by $P(X_0=x_0)$ to get an expression specifically for $P(X_n=x_n|X_0=x_0)$).

Comment: Thank you very much!